# How to flush and restore nftables rules from /etc/nftables.conf?

Tags: nftables

For iptables I used to run `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4` which would flush rules and restore them from /etc/iptables/rules.v4.

For nftables, I found `nft -f /etc/nftables.conf`, but the rules [are not flushed](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nftables)* prior to restoring them from /etc/nftables.conf.

Is there a one-liner that flushes nftables rules and restores them from a file?

*Note that any rules already loaded are not automatically flushed.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `flush ruleset` at the beginning of `/etc/nftables.conf` does the trick. See the notes on https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Atomic_rule_replacement.